# Highlighting particular text ina WPF textbox and registering event to that text only

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

In my WPF application I am having some following type of textbox
[image]

So, In this textbox, the text is not written by user it is generated by program,  i wish to Highlight the particular text  "Enter String Value" and when user clicks on that particular highlighted text only then I wish to fire a event.

Can u guys give me some hint or overview  to achieve this. I tried few tricks but can't get success.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not a direct answer to your question, but why not just have them enter the text in a separate textbox and then make the textbox you are showing readonly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `<RichTextBox>` with `<FlowDocument>`. As I know, TextBox allow you to determinate font (color, size, etc.) only one time, and you wouldn't able to modify color of partial text in one `TextBox`

Comment: Good answer i m also thinking to try the same

Answer (score 2):

I think you can use Regex to get your match from your textbox, and then create Run objects using that match. You can set the Background of the match (runobject.Background = Brushes.Red)